# Enlarging single item in React Native ScrollView

Tags: javascript, react-native, scrollview

I have a ScrollView like so:

```
        <ScrollView>
          {this.state.businessMerchants.map(merchant => (
            <Business
              merchant={merchant}
              key={merchant.id}
            />
          ))}
        </ScrollView>
```

Usually with 2-4 items in it.

I want to highlight the currently top item and make it take up more room (maybe 10% more?). This "top item" would switch as one scrolls through the list.

Is there a more standardized way of doing this, or will I have to do something like use `scrollEventThrottle` and a custom function like so?

Pseudocode below:

```
if((findHeightOfItem + padding) * multiple === itemPos) {
addSizeHere()
}
```

Quite curious about what's the best/most performative way of doing this in React Native.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps:

- Decide the height of each  component `itemHeight`
- Apply onScroll and get current scrolled height `scrolledHeight`
- Have one local state called currentItemIndex which will be decided in onScroll function and will be calculated as `Math.floor(scrolledHeight / itemHeight)`
- Send isCurrentItem as prop to Business component
- Apply necessary styles to Business component depending on value of boolean isCurrentItem
- I would suggest you to use Animated view with transform scale

  ```
  handleScroll = (e) => {
    const currentHeight = e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
    const currentItemIndex = Math.floor(currentHeight / 100);
    this.setState({ currentItemIndex });
  }

  <ScrollView onScroll>
    {this.state.businessMerchants.map((merchant, index) => (
      <Business
        merchant={merchant}
        isCurrentItem={index === this.state.currentItemIndex}
        key={merchant.id}
      />
    ))}
  </ScrollView>
  ```